# Car driving simulator with realistic landscape and roads?

Tags: game

I'm looking for a realistic car driving simulator - by realistic, I mean realistic landscapes.

AFAIK, there are some OK car driving simulators, but don't seem right or aren't what I want; for example, not having nearly enough cars to look like a city or having a focus on racing.

Requirements:

- is a driving game
- must have a realistic landscape
- must have a "free drive" mode
- has a lot of AI cars
- preferably has a freeway
- preferably free or low-priced

I **do not** want:

- a racing game

Willing to use it on Android, Windows, or Linux (includes Steam games).

Does such a game exist?

Comment: Hi. The closest thing to this I came across in the past is a cycling project where developer used googlemaps, his CycleVR app,  virtual reality head set, etc to cycle across the UK. See http://www.cyclevr.com/kickstarter/ This could probably be adpated for cars but you will need to contact the author.